# A single Grunt task to run a shell command and watch task?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Given this `Gruntfile.coffee`, I'd like to keep the `shell:server` task running and outputting to the shell while `watch` checks for changes to front-end assets and reports to the shell when it runs my `:compile` tasks.
All from the same `grunt` command to the same shell.

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')

    coffee:
      compile:
        files:
          'public/js/app.js': 'assets/js/app.coffee'

    stylus:
      compile:
        files:
          'public/css/app.css': 'assets/css/app.styl'

    watch:
      css:
        files: 'assets/**/*.styl'
        tasks: 'stylus'
      javascript:
        files: 'assets/**/*.coffee'
        tasks: 'coffee'

    shell:
      server:
        command: 'supervisor index.coffee'
        options:
          stdout: true

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell')

  grunt.registerTask('work', ['default', 'shell:server', 'watch'])
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee', 'stylus'])
```

A bonus would be eliminating `supervisor` in favor of using Grunt to watch for server changes and rebooting the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. see if one of the tasks provides a `background: true` option (grunt-karma does, for example, IIRC)
2. look into [grunt-parallel](https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-parallel)